# How to simultaneously insert the values of two different tables from single json in springboot?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes:client and contant.Each client can have many contacts.the structure of client class is

```
  public class client{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long clientId;
  private String clientName;
  @OneToMany
  @JsonBackReference
  private List<ContactInfo> contactInfoList;
  //default constructor
  //getter and setter
  }
```

and the contact class is :-

```
   @Entity
   public class ContactInfo {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long contactId;
   @NotNull
   private String mobilePhone;
   @ManyToOne
   @JsonManagedReference
   private Client client;
   //default constructor
   //getter and setter
   }
```

And the classes to fetch data are:-

```
   public interface ContactInfoRepo extends JpaRepository<ContactInfo,Long> {
   }

   public interface clientRepo extends JpaRepository<client,Long> {
   }

    public class ClientController {
    @Autowired
    ClientRepo repo;
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "api/client")
    public void addClient(@RequestBody Client client)throws 
    ConstraintViolationException {
    System.out.println(client.toString());
    repo.save(client);
    }
    }
```

this is the json data I want to save in two different tables;

```
    {
    "clientName":"test",
     "contactInfoList":[{"mobilePhone":"1234"},{"mobilePhone":"12345"} ]
     }
```

I want the contactInfoList to be stored in contact table and the clientName in client table.I am using JPA in spring Boot .When I send the json value the contactInfoList is null.Could someone please help on this?

Comment: What is your problem? Save them one by one but in transaction